# How to hander HTTP 302 in Angular

Tags: angular, httpclient, http-redirect

I have one login API written using the ExpressJS. 
API Meta data
Method: Post
body: {username:'',password:''}

when user authenticated successfully I am redirecting response to https:///#/redirect?token= using res.redirect("https:///#/redirect?token=")

but Angular HttpClient not allowing the application to redirect flow to the mention page.

I have also tried interceptor but it returns error response without an exact location in URL.

Comment: You can manage redirection from Angular. Your ExpressJS just have to return a 200 code if user's data are correct.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `observe: 'response'` to the angular request for a get the response without transforming

```
this.http.delete("url", {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res, 'res');

})
```